# Predictor variable with uneven group sizes

Tags: logistic, categorical-data

I'm running a logistic regression with a categorical independent variable. My categorical IV (an ordinal none, low, medium, high) has a pretty uneven distribution: None (4.28%), Low (36.30%, Medium 30.22%, High 29.21%). I have a total sample size of 3,485 so I don't have any sample size issues, but I'm wondering how these uneven groups might affect my estimation.  Thanks,

Christina

Comment: The group with low observations might have a higher SE, and that's it.

Comment: Thanks..but the small group is my referent, so would that inflate the SEs in the other categories?

Comment: No, but what could inflate the SE of the coefficients is multicollinearity, here it wouldn't matter which group is the reference.